# Search for all files in MyNewFiles where the filename contains an even number and store the result as a variable in bash

Tags: bash

This is what I've got so far:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cd MyNewFiles
pwd
for count in {1..20}; do
    echo "This is file number:" $count > File_$count
done
ls
cd MyNewFiles
chmod a+rwx File_2
chmod ug+rw File_4
chmod u+rwx File_8
ls -lah
```

Comment: var=$(ls /path/to/MyNewFiles | grep -E '[24680]')?

Comment: no such file or directory, i'm getting with that

Comment: Bash scripting isn't Linux-speciifc.

Comment: Do you want any file name that contains an even *digit*, or should the *number as a whole* be even? Is `367` a match?

Comment: sorry forgot to add, so its 20 files made with this for loop                                          
    for count in {1..20}; do
    echo "This is file number:" $count > File_$count
done

Answer (score 0):

```
var=$(ls -1 MyNewFiles/File_* | grep '[02468]$')
```

This assumes the number is at the end of the filename, that you are considering the whole number (and not whether it contains an even digit -- remove the `$` to check for any digit), that your files have no spaces or special characters, and that you don't want to be pedantic and exclude 0 as an even number.

You could also do

```
var=$(cd MyNewFiles; ls -1 File_* | grep '[02468]$')
```

if you don't want the path included.

Note that this is the quick and dirty way to do things (not recommended for production code). The right way to do things is to use arrays, which are a more advanced topic for you, but for posterity, the canonical form (pure bash):

```sh
cd MyNewFiles
declare -a even_files
for x in *
do 
   [[ ${x} =~ [02468]$ ]] && even_files+=( "${x}" )
done
# Sample usage
rm "${even_files[@]}"
```

Comment: spot-on for the first half of it what about storing the result as a variable?

Comment: I've updated it, but how it is stored in a variable depends in part on what you want to do with it later. Assuming you have more than one such file, you may want to save it as an array; what I've written up returns it as a newline-separated string, which may work for your purposes. However, I'm not sure how familiar you are with using arrays.

Comment: thanks for the help I'm a complete noob lol and what I wanted to do was store Search for all files in the current directory where the filename
contains an even number and store the result as a variable
For each result in myVariable:
Delete file

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Try `even_files=(MyNewFiles/*[02468])` or `even_files=(MyNewFiles/*[02468]*)`. No need for `cd`, `declare`, or the loop.